# Pandas csv NaN values replace by the left side columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm new to python and pandas.
I have 3 columns in csv file and data type of columns is string.

example

```
 col1  col2  col3
 ABC   XYZ   NaN
 PQR   LMN   QPR
```

I'm using pandas to read the csv file. I want to replace NaN with left side column cell value. Here I want to replace col3 1st value with col2 1st value 
so output will be like

```
col1  col2 col3
ABC   XYZ   XYZ
PQR   LMN   QPR
```

Please help me in this.
Thanks.

Comment: have a look at `pd.where()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['col3'] = df.col3.combine_first(df.col2)

print (df)
  col1 col2 col3
0  ABC  XYZ  XYZ
1  PQR  LMN  QPR
```

Or:

```
df['col3'] = df.col3.fillna(df.col2)

print (df)
  col1 col2 col3
0  ABC  XYZ  XYZ
1  PQR  LMN  QPR
```

If you want something more dynamic, use [`last_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html):

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda x:  x[x.last_valid_index()], axis=1)

print (df)
  col1 col2 col3
0  ABC  XYZ  XYZ
1  PQR  LMN  QPR
```

Comment: Thanks Jexrael...!

Comment: Glad can help you!